# Why does a part of HTML code disappear (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS.

I've written following code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h3 ng-include="'product-title.html'"/>
        <section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
```

When I open the browser I see that the `<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">` part is not present in the resulting HTML code.

[image: Screenshot]

You can find the entire source [here](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/js1/src).

How can I fix this problem (make the `section` part appear in the browser) ?

Comment: Where do you close the h3 tag? If the HTML is invalid it's no wonder it doesn't render correctly. Run it through a validator.

Comment: @Juhana `<h3 ng-include="'product-title.html'"/>` The h3 tag is closed properly IMHO.

Comment: h3 is not a self-closing tag. Try with a proper end tag.

Comment: @Juhana That was it. Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your

```
<h3 ng-include="'product-title.html'"/>
```

ng-include has to be used in pair tags as referred here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

So change it like that

```
<h3 ng-include="'product-title.html'"></h3>
```